# parseFloat() function parses an argument and returns a floating point number but with me after using it Retrieve Nan

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm

In my Form there is (whole number Field in `CRM` ) and in JavaScript that retrieve value I used `ParseFloat` function but retrieved to me `NaN` but I want to Retrieve like (12.00).

```
function SetLookup(fieldName, Id, Name, LogicalName) 
{
    var value = new Array();
    value[0] = new Object();
    value[0].id = Id;
    value[0].name = Name;
    value[0].typename = LogicalName;
    var getAttribute = Xrm.Page.getAttribute(fieldName);
    if (getAttribute != null) {
        getAttribute.setValue(parseFloat(value));
        getAttribute.setSubmitMode("always");
    }
}
```

Comment: And what's in the `value`param, looks like an object?

Comment: @anderssonola SetLookup("ph_completionpercent", results[0].ph_completionprogress.Id, results[0].ph_completionprogress.Name, results[0].ph_completionprogress.LogicalName);

Comment: So what's passed in to parseFloat(value) is it a float? Looking at the code, it looks like a array...`var value = new Array()`

Comment: Yes Value is an array @anderssonola

Comment: Value has to be a parsable float like `parseFloat('1.23')` and not an array with random stuff in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

parseFloat() expects a string input.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat

However your code tries to pass it an array of objects.